# What data format is that? And how to parse it (python)?

Tags: python, data-formats

Games from Valve use following [data format](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/440/scripts/items/items_game.9aee6b38c52d8814124b8fbfc8d13e7b1faa944f.txt)

```
"name1"
{
    "name2"  "value2"
    "name3"
    {
        "name4" "value4"
    }
}
```

Does this format have a name or is it just self made?

Can I parse it in python?

Comment: No, JSON would need {"key":"value"} for dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that it has a name, but it seems very straightforward: a node consists of a key and either a value or a set of values that are themselves either plain strings or sets of key-value pairs.  It would be trivial to parse recursively, and maps cleanly to a structure of nested python dictionaries.

Comment: yes, straightforward. I just havent had experience parsing anything in python, so I guess there should definetely something already exist for such tasks.

Comment: I don't think that something exists specifically for this file format, but you might be interested in some undocumented functionality called ``re.Scanner``.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/693818/327038

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess re.Scanner is exactly what I need for as less lines of code as possible. Was looking for proper solution. Gl.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like their own format, called Valve Data Format. Documentation [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues), I don't know if there is a parser available in python, but here is a question about [parsing it in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301511/parsing-valve-data-format-files-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like JSON without comma and colon seperators. You could parse it manually since it has the same logic to it.

Seems to consist of name-value pairs, so after a name, finding a '{' or another string in "" would mean a value.

A composite structure of custom classes would make it easy to handle.  As Matti John linked, there is documentation.

Comment: [Here](http://gjordis.kapsi.fi/index.php/9-json-parser-python) is one type of quick and dirty parsing I used for a similar format (malformed json). The downside is that I use the names to find the values. But it might be of some help.

Comment: You parse it manually. This is exactly what I wanted to avoid =).